# How to define an ADT struct in header file that will be defined in implementation file

Tags: c, interface, abstract-data-type, incomplete-type

I have a header file that declares an ADT modeling a tuple. The header contains a declaration of the struct as `typedef struct Tuple * Tuple;` The corresponding implementation file defines this as

```
struct Tuple
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    int w;
};
```

The problem is that I want to import just the header file in client code (such as a test file or a file containing main). I don't want to include the .c implementation file. Not doing so however results in an error message when attempting code from client code such as:

```
Tuple tuple = ( Tuple ) calloc( 1, THREE_TUPLE_COORDINATES * sizeof( Tuple ) );
tuple->x ;
```

that reads as follows: `error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct Tuple’`

Is it possible leave leave the struct incomplete/undefined in the header and then define it in the implementation file or is this not done/not best practice?

Comment: Do not hide pointer nature behind a typedef.  Doing so is very bad form, because it creates fertile ground for bugs revolving around mismatched levels of indirection, failure to free, and similar.

Comment: You can use `struct Tuple` as an abstract data type (or an *incomplete* data type in the terminology of the language spec) without any header at all.  But if you want to be able to skip the `struct` keyword, contrary to my own usual recommendation, then simply `typedef struct Tuple Tuple`.  That would probably be worth putting in a header.

Comment: Note: the `sizeof(Tuple)` in the code presented is a great example of the kind of error that hiding pointer nature behind a `typedef` invites.  It computes the size *of a pointer*, whereas what you want is the size of the thing that that particular kind of pointer poiints to.

Comment: Define the API to your ADT as using pointers. Don't make the actual typedef a pointer, hiding pointers behind typedef is just confusing for everyone including yourself. You might find this helpful: [How to do private encapsulation in C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/283888)

Comment: As for your calloc problem you can create a constructor and pass the allocation method along as a parameter to it. Or just allocate every object dynamically if that's an option (PC/hosted system programming).

Answer (score 2):

> `error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct Tuple’`
>
> Is it possible leave leave the struct incomplete/undefined in the
> header and then define it in the implementation file or is this not
> done/not best practice?

You cannot use an *abstract* / *incomplete* data type in any context where the actual definition  matters.  Such contexts include declaring instances, accessing members, and determining the size.  How is the compiler supposed to know how much space to reserve?  Or where within that space to find the member with a particular name?  Or whether such a member even exists?

You *can* provide functions for most of those things in the same translation unit(s) where the type is defined, and then let other translation units rely on those functions.  All instances obtained that way will need to be dynamically allocated, and all member accesses will incur the cost of a function call.  This sort of thing is sometimes done, but it's also often *not* done.  Do think carefully about what you want to gain by doing it.